# list the top 5 users by time spent watching videos

Tags: mysql, sql

Table1:

```
***Publisher*** with following columns:
o    **Publisher_id** ; unique ID for each publisher
o    **Video_id** ; unique ID for each video
o    **Video_duration**; in  minutes for each video
```

Table2:

```
***Consumer*** with the following columns:
o    **Video_id** ; unique ID for each video
o    **User_id** ; unique ID for each customer
o    **Dateid** ; the date on which the consumer watched a video
```

Example:

```
Publisher_id    Video_id    Video_duration  
1   1   2   
1   2   3   
1   3   2   
1   4   5   
2   6   2   
2   7   2   
2   8   20  
3   10  2   
3   11  3   
3   12  3   
1   23  100 
5   9   8
```

```
Video_id    User_id Date_id
1           44      20210615
2           44      20210615
11          33      20210614
6           44      20210612
```

I think I mostly need to figure out how to sum up the time spent watching videos per user_id and then to corroborate that using a limit 5 select, but I can't figure how to combine these 2 selects

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  Sample data and desired results are also helpful, as is an appropriate database tag.

Comment: I've tried something along these lines (doesn't work, as  sum() is not used correctly) select user_id from consumption_info as c 
join publisher_info as p
on c.video_id = p.video_id
order by sum(video_duration);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Video_duration) 
FROM       Consumer 
INNER JOIN Publisher USING (Video_id)
GROUP BY User_id
ORDER BY SUM(Video_duration) DESC
LIMIT 5
```